# Change Text Size using QListWidgetItem class

Tags: c++, qt, graphics, qtwidgets

How can we change the size of a text if we are using QListWidgetItem reference for the operations?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, use `QListWidgetItem::font()` method to get the current font for an item, then change its size (using `setPointSize`) and set the modified font to item using `QListWidgetItem::setFont(const QFont&)`.